# Prevent Checkbox being selected based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have checkbox for games and based on what is selected, certain checkbox should be prevented from being checked.i.e if either BRIDGE,  BUKHAR,  CRICKET,  GOLF,  SCRABBLE  or SWIMMING is selected, all other games should be prevented from selcetion except   TUG  OF  WAR,MINI MARATHON, ATHLETICS, FOOTBALL, ROLLER BLADING AND GAMMING.

Below is my HTMl Code:

```
<ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_1_1"><li class="gchoice_1_1_1">
<input name="input_1.1" type="checkbox" value="Athletics" id="choice_1_1_1" tabindex="1">
<label for="choice_1_1_1" id="label_1_1_1">Athletics</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_2">
<input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" value="Badminton" id="choice_1_1_2" tabindex="2">
<label for="choice_1_1_2" id="label_1_1_2">Badminton</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_3">
<input name="input_1.3" type="checkbox" value="Bridge" id="choice_1_1_3" tabindex="3">
<label for="choice_1_1_3" id="label_1_1_3">Bridge</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_4">
<input name="input_1.4" type="checkbox" value="Bukhar" id="choice_1_1_4" tabindex="4">
<label for="choice_1_1_4" id="label_1_1_4">Bukhar</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_5">
<input name="input_1.5" type="checkbox" value="Chess" id="choice_1_1_5" tabindex="5">
<label for="choice_1_1_5" id="label_1_1_5">Chess</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_6">
<input name="input_1.6" type="checkbox" value="Cricket" id="choice_1_1_6" tabindex="6">
<label for="choice_1_1_6" id="label_1_1_6">Cricket</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_7">
<input name="input_1.7" type="checkbox" value="Darts" id="choice_1_1_7" tabindex="7">
<label for="choice_1_1_7" id="label_1_1_7">Darts</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_8">
<input name="input_1.8" type="checkbox" value="Football" id="choice_1_1_8" tabindex="8">
<label for="choice_1_1_8" id="label_1_1_8">Football</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_9">
<input name="input_1.9" type="checkbox" value="Gaming" id="choice_1_1_9" tabindex="9">
<label for="choice_1_1_9" id="label_1_1_9">Gaming</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_11">
<input name="input_1.11" type="checkbox" value="Golf" id="choice_1_1_11" tabindex="10">
<label for="choice_1_1_11" id="label_1_1_11">Golf</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_12">
<input name="input_1.12" type="checkbox" value="Marathon" id="choice_1_1_12" tabindex="11">
<label for="choice_1_1_12" id="label_1_1_12">Marathon</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_13">
<input name="input_1.13" type="checkbox" value="Roller-Blading" id="choice_1_1_13" tabindex="12">
<label for="choice_1_1_13" id="label_1_1_13">Roller-Blading</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_14">
<input name="input_1.14" type="checkbox" value="Scrabble" id="choice_1_1_14" tabindex="13">
<label for="choice_1_1_14" id="label_1_1_14">Scrabble</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_15">
<input name="input_1.15" type="checkbox" value="Snooker" id="choice_1_1_15" tabindex="14">
<label for="choice_1_1_15" id="label_1_1_15">Snooker</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_16">
<input name="input_1.16" type="checkbox" value="Squash" id="choice_1_1_16" tabindex="15">
<label for="choice_1_1_16" id="label_1_1_16">Squash</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_17">
<input name="input_1.17" type="checkbox" value="Swimming" id="choice_1_1_17" tabindex="16">
<label for="choice_1_1_17" id="label_1_1_17">Swimming</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_18">
<input name="input_1.18" type="checkbox" value="Table-Tennis" id="choice_1_1_18" tabindex="17">
<label for="choice_1_1_18" id="label_1_1_18">Table-Tennis</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_19">
<input name="input_1.19" type="checkbox" value="Tennis" id="choice_1_1_19" tabindex="18">
<label for="choice_1_1_19" id="label_1_1_19">Tennis</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_21">
<input name="input_1.21" type="checkbox" value="Tug of War" id="choice_1_1_21" tabindex="19">
<label for="choice_1_1_21" id="label_1_1_21">Tug of War</label>
</li><li class="gchoice_1_1_22">
<input name="input_1.22" type="checkbox" value="Volleyball" id="choice_1_1_22" tabindex="20">
<label for="choice_1_1_22" id="label_1_1_22">Volleyball</label>
```

Jquery :

```
$('input[id^="id"]').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.is("#choice_1_1_1")) {
    if ($("#choice_1_1_1:checked").length > 0) {
        $("#choice_1_1_2").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
    } else {
        $("#choice_1_1_3").prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

});

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqap90nd/)

Comment: You can use two different classes

Comment: @Azzi how do i go about doing that?

Comment: 1 doubt which may not be related to your problem. I was just thinking why all this tabindex are of different value?

Answer (score 0):

As @Azzi suggested,

Add `BRIDGE, BUKHAR, CRICKET, GOLF, SCRABBLE or SWIMMING` class `group-1`
and
`TUG OF WAR,MINI MARATHON, ATHLETICS, FOOTBALL, ROLLER BLADING` AND `GAMMING` class `group-3`, everything else will be `group-2`

Following is a code snippet(taken from your code) just to give you an idea. Its not a complete solution, but you will get an idea about how to go ahead.

```
$('li input').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(".group-1")) {
    if($this.is(':checked') == true) {
      if ($(".group-2").length > 0) {
        $(".group-2").prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
      } else {
        $(".group-3").prop("disabled", false);
      }
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".group1").click(function() {
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

  //check any other elements check in same class
  if (!checked) {
    $(".group1").not(this).each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checked = true;
        return;
      }
    });
  }
  $(".group2").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", checked) //dissable 
      .prop('checked', false); //checked state false
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_1_1">
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_1">
    <input name="input_1.1" type="checkbox" value="Athletics" id="choice_1_1_1" tabindex="1">
    <label for="choice_1_1_1" id="label_1_1_1">Athletics</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_2">
    <input name="input_1.2" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Badminton" id="choice_1_1_2" tabindex="2">
    <label for="choice_1_1_2" id="label_1_1_2">Badminton</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_3">
    <input name="input_1.3" type="checkbox" class="group1" value="Bridge" id="choice_1_1_3" tabindex="3">
    <label for="choice_1_1_3" id="label_1_1_3">Bridge</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_4">
    <input name="input_1.4" type="checkbox" class="group1" value="Bukhar" id="choice_1_1_4" tabindex="4">
    <label for="choice_1_1_4" id="label_1_1_4">Bukhar</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_5">
    <input name="input_1.5" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Chess" id="choice_1_1_5" tabindex="5">
    <label for="choice_1_1_5" id="label_1_1_5">Chess</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_6">
    <input name="input_1.6" type="checkbox" class="group1" value="Cricket" id="choice_1_1_6" tabindex="6">
    <label for="choice_1_1_6" id="label_1_1_6">Cricket</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_7">
    <input name="input_1.7" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Darts" id="choice_1_1_7" tabindex="7">
    <label for="choice_1_1_7" id="label_1_1_7">Darts</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_8">
    <input name="input_1.8" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Football" id="choice_1_1_8" tabindex="8">
    <label for="choice_1_1_8" id="label_1_1_8">Football</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_9">
    <input name="input_1.9" type="checkbox" value="Gaming" id="choice_1_1_9" tabindex="9">
    <label for="choice_1_1_9" id="label_1_1_9">Gaming</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_11">
    <input name="input_1.11" type="checkbox" class="group1" value="Golf" id="choice_1_1_11" tabindex="10">
    <label for="choice_1_1_11" id="label_1_1_11">Golf</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_12">
    <input name="input_1.12" type="checkbox" value="Marathon" id="choice_1_1_12" tabindex="11">
    <label for="choice_1_1_12" id="label_1_1_12">Marathon</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_13">
    <input name="input_1.13" type="checkbox" value="Roller-Blading" id="choice_1_1_13" tabindex="12">
    <label for="choice_1_1_13" id="label_1_1_13">Roller-Blading</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_14">
    <input name="input_1.14" type="checkbox" class="group1" value="Scrabble" id="choice_1_1_14" tabindex="13">
    <label for="choice_1_1_14" id="label_1_1_14">Scrabble</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_15">
    <input name="input_1.15" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Snooker" id="choice_1_1_15" tabindex="14">
    <label for="choice_1_1_15" id="label_1_1_15">Snooker</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_16">
    <input name="input_1.16" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Squash" id="choice_1_1_16" tabindex="15">
    <label for="choice_1_1_16" id="label_1_1_16">Squash</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_17">
    <input name="input_1.17" type="checkbox" class="group1" value="Swimming" id="choice_1_1_17" tabindex="16">
    <label for="choice_1_1_17" id="label_1_1_17">Swimming</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_18">
    <input name="input_1.18" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Table-Tennis" id="choice_1_1_18" tabindex="17">
    <label for="choice_1_1_18" id="label_1_1_18">Table-Tennis</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_19">
    <input name="input_1.19" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Tennis" id="choice_1_1_19" tabindex="18">
    <label for="choice_1_1_19" id="label_1_1_19">Tennis</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_21">
    <input name="input_1.21" type="checkbox" value="Tug of War" id="choice_1_1_21" tabindex="19">
    <label for="choice_1_1_21" id="label_1_1_21">Tug of War</label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_1_22">
    <input name="input_1.22" type="checkbox" class="group2" value="Volleyball" id="choice_1_1_22" tabindex="20">
    <label for="choice_1_1_22" id="label_1_1_22">Volleyball</label>
```

Here is the working code..